# Adding more to the "How to Ask" sidebar help box

Tags: feature-request

Can we expand a little on the "provide details" statement? Specifically, I would like to see a tip for including software version numbers and operating systems.

Most of my comments are requests for the author to include this information, and I think that this would speed things up around here.

---

**Example:**

[image: how to ask]

Comment: I'd appreciate a rewording to *Provide **relevant** details* as well.

Comment: As if anyone actually read that measage... Most people who are capable of reading and writing a coherent sentence will probably add enough details. And not to forget the [ask] page that everyone has to look at anyway.

Comment: @slhck I'm fairly sure the *How to Ask* page is only put upon users on Stack Overflow, for the rest of the network it's just another hidden side page.

Comment: Ohhh that's interesting @DMA57361 — I thought *both* ask/answer pages were compulsory. I stand corrected. In that case — why don't we actually force new users to look at this before asking? It wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @slhck yeah, try hitting the ask button on SO and SU using Private Browsing (or whatever your browser of choice calls it) and you'll see. Unlike SO, we (and other SE sites) are capable of reviewing pretty much every question as they come in so can monitor quality more closely. That said, I'm of the "people won't read this anyway and will still create rubbish" school of thought - I mean look at some of the blurg on SO - but it can help trim a proportion of "bad" cases.

Comment: Yup. You'll never get rid of the really bad stuff, but I have to agree that we get it in quantities that are easier to digest. It however also depends on the number of users who are willing to actively moderate (edit, request for clarification, downvote, flag/close).